# My donut is wavy instead of bumpy after using procedural displacement!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, displacement, procedural

Hi I am following blender guru's 2019 tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh5gAQLtOls) and this is what I want it to look like: [image]

But it looks like this, slightly wavy instead of bumpy:  [image]

This is my node setup: [image]

and this is his [image]

What should I do to make my donut bumpy instead of wavy?

Comment: It looks like your donut is bigger than his.  Try  reducing the Noise Texture scale a little and increasing the scale on the Displacement node until you get a rougher look.  It could also be that your Subdivision Surface mod has too few levels.

Comment: Have you Ctrl-A applied the scale of your donut?